# separate string inputs

Tags: java, loops

I am able to separate the characters in string input, but my problem is this:

`Enter an integer: 123`

Output is:

`Individual digits: 1 Individual digits: 2 Individual digits: 3`

It also copies the "individual digits" which is not intended.. here's my code

```
public class gradedExer1A {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        int len = input.length();


        for(int i = 0; i < len ; i++) {

            char in = input.charAt(i);

            System.out.print("Individual digits: " + in + " ");

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: So what is the expected output? Do you actually want that message to be displayed once? Just think of it: - The thing which you don't want multiple times, should not be inside a loop.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
System.out.print("Individual digits: ");
for(int i = 0; i < len ; i++) {

    char in = input.charAt(i);
    System.out.print(in + " ");

}
```